# Create UIViewController programmatically with navbar along with done button and UITextView for ModalView Presentation

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to create UIViewController programmatically for ModalView presentation on the main window of the application and in this UIViewController on top i have is Navigation bar with done button to dismiss the view and below the navigation bar it has UITextView.

So my question is that the UITextview which i want to create below the navigation bar will come in the ViewdidLoad Method or i m doing right to show separate medthod to setup textview .

In the Infoviewcontroller.h file have following code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface Infoviewcontroller : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>{
    UITextView *textView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextView *textView;
@property (nonatomic, assign) UINavigationBar *navBar;
@end
```

Then in the infoviewcontroller.m file have the following code:

```
#import "Infoviewcontroller.h"
@implementation Infoviewcontroller
@synthesize textView;
@synthesize navBar;

-(void)dealloc{
   [textView release];
   [navBar release];
   [super dealloc];
}

-(void)setupTextView {
    self.textView = [[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame] autorelease];
    self.textView.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"System Bold" size:13];
    self.textView.delegate = self;
    self.textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.textView.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentCenter;
    self.textView.text = @"This is UITextView\nThis is UITextView\nThis is UITextView\nThis is UITextView"; 
    [self.view addSubview: self.textView];    
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];
    UINavigationItem *navItem = [[[UINavigationItem alloc]         initWithTitle:@"ModalViewControllerTest"] autorelease];
    UIBarButtonItem *done = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissView:)] autorelease];
    navItem.rightBarButtonItem = done;
    navBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:navItem];
    [self.view addSubview:navBar];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding creation of UINavigationBar programmatically, I found following blog post helpful http://cps.liridesce.com/?p=100. Example overrides *loadView* rather than *viewDidLoad* method, but I think in your case using *viewDidLoad* should have the same effect.

I would also add *viewDidUnload* where I would set to *nil* navBar and textView properties.

I'm not quite sure why you need separate *setupTextView* method, unless you are calling it from different places of your UIViewController. I would just keep everything together in *viewDidUnload*.